# What screen resolution should my web app target for an average non-technical users?

Tags: user-interface

I noticed StackOverflow appears to be targeting screen resolution widths of 1024px or more.  I also checked Amazon, NBC, MSN, & AOL which target more lay users, and they all appear to be targeting the same width.

Is 1024px the current recommended width for web apps targeting the largest cross-section of users who use default monitor resolution/browser size?

Comment: My screen has a width of some 1900 pixels. My current browser window has a width of some 1100 pixels. You may be using the wrong assumptions here.

Comment: Presumably if you know how to resize the window you're considered 'sophisticated'.

Comment: I have edited the wording somewhat based on John's further comments of what his intended meaning was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use liquid layout. Then you can easily accommodate everyone from ~800 to ~1600 width, and with a bit more work and care even lower-resolution devices too. This also gives users @1024 some leeway to zoom the page if they find the text too small.

Remember there'll be things like netbooks which don't have the big screens we expect today. You can get away with a horizontal scrollbar, but if you have to scroll the page just to get the main body of text in, you're lost.

Answer (score 2):

Before sounding so condescending, you may want to read up on the modern user base. Netbooks. PDAs. Smartphones. Smartbooks (you **do** know what those are, being very sophisticated, right?). Programmers who have their screen in portrait orientaton. People who stack their windows side by side. Kiosks.

**UPDATE** As per conversation with John, I edited the question to change the tenor a bit to reflect his original intent. However, the original paragraph that I wrote is still true- I haven't seen the latest statistics but the days of "90% of users have AxB resultion/window size on their browser" are probably forever gone, what with wide screen laptops and mobile devices. Makes life more exciting for UI designers :)

Having said that, to develop a **really** usable web site, you need to couple flowing layout with, ideally, ability to use portlets and portal framework (think My Yahoo), so people can choose the page layout most comfortable for them.

Comment: The term 'unsophisticated' was meant to point out that I'm not targeting the same audience as might be reading this question, but a more lay person. It was definitely not intended to be 'condescending', but if you have a better term which might communicate the same thing, feel free to edit.

Comment: And a portal framework is beyond our scope at this moment ... but thanks anyway.

Comment: 1) I have a nagging suspicion (unsubstanciated at the moment) that YUI may provide an easy-to-use portals.
2) I edited the question - please check if it makes sense now (I'm ESL so the wording might be far from perfect).

Comment: However, the substance of my original comment stands - I haven't seen the latest statistics but the days of "90% of users have AxB resultion/window size on their browser" are probably forever gone, what with wide screen laptops and mobile devices. Makes life more exciting for UI designers :)

Answer (score 2):

make a good use of **[960.gs](http://960.gs)** and you will set everything that you need to start a good web site :)

[image]
<sub>(source: [balexandre.com](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-09-26_1559.png))</sub>

> The **960 Grid System** is an effort to streamline web development workflow by providing commonly used dimensions, based on a width of **960 pixels**. There are two variants: 12 and 16 columns, which can be used separately or in tandem.

960 GS it's a lovely start, doing web or images, they have a complete template for almost any good design program (Photoshop, Ilustrator, Fireworks, InDesign, etc) as well a **[CSS generator](http://www.spry-soft.com/grids/)** and a **[Grid Overlay](http://gridder.andreehansson.se/)** to help you with the website.

I use it and it's fantastic! check out the [demo](http://960.gs/demo.html)

---

> Nettuts has a **[tutorial](http://nettuts.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/prototyping-with-the-grid-960-css-framework/)** and **[video](http://nettuts.com/videos/screencasts/a-detailed-look-at-the-960-css-framework/)**. WooThemes wrote a **[post](http://www.woothemes.com/2008/12/why-we-love-960gs/)** entitled “Why we love 960.gs” and use it as a starting point for their WordPress themes. Spanish speakers can also check out tutorials by **[Jepser Bernardino](http://jepserbernardino.com/2009/03/960-grid-un-framework-para-css/)** and **[Miguel Angel Alvarez](http://www.desarrolloweb.com/manuales/maquetacion-css-960-grid-system.html)**.

Comment: Blueprint is another CSS framework based on the same concept. We've had a lot of success with it at PostRank.com

Comment: I do prefer 960.gs over BP, more templates, much cleaner and easy :) well, at least for me, eheheh.

Comment: Moved from @nitebrain's answer: I think 960 is an abuse of the intended CSS design principles. It does work, but so does embedding your markup with your content. Correct me if I am wrong, but I thought that the purpose of CSS was to separate the content from the layout, using descriptive CSS tags to describe the content's "contents". What 960 does is to use tags to describe the layout, therefore littering the content with embedded layout information, which seems to be against the whole idea of CSS. Maybe I am missing the point of CSS or 960. Pls chime in with feedback if u think I am confused.

Comment: everyone has their opinion on everything, I do respect yours, but I rather work with 960 or BluePrint than do everything from scratch :)
BTW, you can change the tags anytime if it's that important to you :)

Comment: This is just like the old days when web designers who can't figure out CSS use tables to layout html elements....

Answer (score 1):

Unsophisticated? I think that's a bit of a rude way to describe  the unwashed masses. I suppose every one and their dog has a 1024px width monitor now thanks to the likes of dell and others...

Comment: And calling them "unwashed" isn't? ;)

Answer (score 1):

The maximum I would consider targeting as my "base" is 1280x1024, but I would be much more likely to go 1024x768.

That said, in my current projects I try to do a liquid layout with a min-width of 800 to accomidate netbooks and usually a max-width of around 1000px (970 usually). Of course, I also have the luxury of designing for myself, so I have the privilege of telling IE6 users that they should upgrade, which makes the liquid layouts much easier to design.

Answer (score 0):

Summary:

> **Design with your browser's *inner* dimensions set to 1250x668 to satisfy 92.7% of users.**

I like being stats-driven.  To this end, W3Schools has a nice [Browser Display Statistics](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp) page, which they update periodically with new statistics on how common each screen resolution is.

As of January 2015, 92.7% of browsers visiting W3Schools pages were attached to displays larger than 1024x768, though 39.3% of all displays were limited to 768 pixels in height (or lower), mostly due to the 33% of them having 1366x768 displays.

Unfortunately, W3Schools measured *screen* resolution rather than the inner dimensions used for rendering web page content.  It'd be real nice to get stats on users' [window.innerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth) and [window.innerHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight) instead.

Because we don't have these, we have to reserve room for window decorations that may be larger than our own, as well as browser widgets that may further take away from the space dedicated to rendering a web site.  Additionally, not all users browse the web in a maximized web browser, though I think we can ignore that if we assume lower-resolution displays will have maximized browsers.

Windows 7 seems the biggest offender at eating up screen real estate, with what I'm measuring as 30-40px for the task bar (I had to search for a screen shot, as I don't run Windows).  Firefox with titlebar, menubar, bookmarks toolbar, and status bar eats another 159px while the slimmer modern FF only consumes 64px.  Let's use the slim version and assume around 100px of vertical space will be lost.  Maximized browsers don't appear to consume any extra horizontal space, so you really only need to account for the scroll bar, but I'd reserve a few pixels for window edges just in case, bringing us up to 30px.

A few years ago (when I did more web design than I do today), I'd size my own browser to an *inner* size of 800x550 and made sure that most pages would not have scroll bars.  Nowadays, it looks like that can be expanded to around an *inner* size of 1250x668.

You can check your inner size by putting this in your location bar:

```
javascript:alert(window.innerWidth + "x" + window.innerHeight)
```

Those values are read-only; you used to be able to run something like this to resize your inner dimensions, but (thanks to abusive advertisers) [it no longer works](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=565541#c24):

```
javascript:window.resizeTo(window.outerWidth-window.innerWidth+1250,window.outerHeight-window.innerHeight+668)
```

**One parting note:** Just because you're assuming a certain size doesn't mean you shouldn't ensure that your site still works at smaller resolutions.  The page can be ugly, but *it must be functional!*